# Combining 3 bs4.element.ResultSet's into one master ResultSet

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a Python script to scrape the top 100 games from metacritic.com.

I used the bs4 findAll() to create a ResultSet for the list of elements with {"class":"product_row game"}.

When I checked len(prods) it returned "98". Upon inspection I noticed that the first and last elements on the list have {"class":"product_row game first"}  and {"class":"product_row game last"} respectively.

My plan was to create 3 separate ResultSet's and combine them, but I cannot find the resources online to do this. Is it feasible/smart to do it this was? If so, a pointer would be appreciated. If not, how should I change my approach?

Thanks in advance,
Gavin :)

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/score/metascore/all/all/filtered?sort=desc'

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

web_byte = urlopen(req).read()
webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')
urlopen(req).close()

page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")

prod_f = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"product_row game first"})
prods = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"product_row game"})
prod_l = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"product_row game last"})
```

Comment: why do you want to create three different Results sets.. since all the data points can be obtained with a simple findAll with class name "product_row"

Comment: @SarthakNegi is it possible to do this? I thought that the class would have to match up perfectly in order for the findAll() to work. How would I write the finaAll() to include all three so?

Comment: Sorted . thanks all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine them all into one ResultSet by adding one line:

```
prods.extend([prod_f, prod_l])
```

If you run `print(len(prods))`, it now has all 100 items

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work len(prods) is 98, but after the appends it becomes 3; not 100

Comment: Sick! thanks a million. Was grinding all day on this. TY!

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention why you want to combine the three. But if you want to iterate through all the elements, you could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools

node_iterator = itertools.chain([prod_f], prods, [prod_l])
for node in node_iterator:
    do_whatever_with(node)
```

Note that `find()` returns a `Tag` object, while `findAll()` returns a `ResultSet` object that can be iterated over to yield `Tag` objects. Since `itertools.chain` expects all arguments to be iterables, I create a list of `Tag` objects using `[prod_f]`/`[prod_l]` in the code example above.

Comment: Good points on the find() and pointing out that I did not provide a reason - sorry about that. I was to keep them in a bs4 object so I can loop through them and write the titles , scores and release dates to a csv

Comment: OK I see. So given the example code above you can do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are after is simply "get all divs that has class product_row and class game", then using a CSS selector is likely the best approach:

```
prods = page_soup.select('div.product_row.game')
```

Documentation links:

- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class
- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing a Python script to scrape the top 100 games from
>   metacritic.com.

```
divs = page_soup.find_all('div',{'class':'product_rows'})
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])

pos = 0
for row in divs[0].find_all('div',{'class':'product_row'}):
    data = []
    for item in row.find_all('div',{'class':'product_item'}):
        clean_data = item.text.strip() 
        clean_data = clean_data.replace('\n',' ')
        data.append(clean_data)
    temp_df.loc[pos] = data  
    pos+=1

print(temp_df.head())
```

Output

```
       A   B                                                  C          D  \
0  1.  99  The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time          ...  User: 9.1   
1  2.  98  Tony Hawk's Pro Skater 2                      ...  User: 7.4   
2  3.  98  Grand Theft Auto IV                           ...  User: 7.5   
3  4.  98  Red Dead Redemption 2                         ...  User: tbd   
4  5.  98  SoulCalibur                                   ...  User: 8.7   

              E  
0  Nov 23, 1998  
1  Sep 20, 2000  
2  Apr 29, 2008  
3  Oct 26, 2018  
4   Sep 8, 1999
```

Comment: clean_data = clean_data.replace('\n',' ')

Brilliant touch. cheers